# Keep getting unauthorized when registering devices in Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have followed every example to a 't' and cannot get Azure Notification Hubs to return anything other than the following 401 message: "MalformedToken: The credentials contained in the authorization header are not in the WRAP format."

I have tried the namespace access keys and the notification hub keys to no avail.  I have followed the examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495630.aspx and have been unable to get it to work.  I changed all the account specific settings like namespace, notification hub name and authorization key.

```js
var registrationXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">" +
                "<content type=\"application/xml\">" +
                    "<GcmTemplateRegistrationDescription xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect\">" +
                        "<GcmRegistrationId>" + {GCMRegID} + "</GcmRegistrationId> " +
                        "<BodyTemplate><![CDATA[ {\"data\": { \"message\": \"$(msg)\" } }]]></BodyTemplate>" +
                    "</GcmTemplateRegistrationDescription>" +
                "</content>" +
            "</entry>";

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://{myNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{myHubName}/registrations/?api-version=2015-01",
                headers: { 'Authorization': '{myAccessKey}', 'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8', 'x-ms-version': '2015-01' },
                data: registrationXML,
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Showing the code you are using to make the call would be handy.

Comment: The linked documentation specifies that a `PUT` operation is performed - your code example does a `POST`.

Comment: PUT throws the same error.

Comment: @Bloodhound You deleted your other question after I went to all the trouble to answer it. Here: I found the source code for this project, searched for "F6", searched for the resulting term "execute-project", searched for the resulting term, "execute_project", followed the code a bit, found the eventual call to a sort of generic "call executable" helper. Here it is: `https://github.com/ninja-ide/ninja-ide/blob/b4e057617f032eda40438738a55ed1adcbbc8158/ninja_ide/gui/tools_dock/tools_dock.py#L202`. You should be able to patch that to run as root/sudo.

Answer (score 2):

The value for {myAccessKey} should look something like:

```
SharedAccessSignature sig=<signature-string>&se=<expiry>&skn=<keyName>&sr=<URL-encoded-resourceURI>
```

Documentation for constructing the signature is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn170477.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you create Authorization token for 2 hours.

```
static string GenerateSasToken(Uri uri, string sasKeyValue, string sasKeyName)
        {
            var targetUri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uri.ToString().ToLower(), Encoding.UTF8).ToLower();
            var expiresOnDate = Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds) + 2*60*60;
            var toSign = targetUri + "\n" + expiresOnDate;

            var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sasKeyValue);
            var mac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
            mac.Initialize();
            var rawHmac = mac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toSign));
            var signature = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(rawHmac), Encoding.UTF8);

            var token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + targetUri + "&sig=" + signature + "&se=" + expiresOnDate + "&skn=" + sasKeyName;
            return token;
        }
```

Thanks,
Sateesh